# Make Fixed div in relative div

Tags: html, css, less

i'm trying to make fixed div insert relative div . i created the `textarea.comment` to make the user comment but i need it in the bottom of `conversations` div

Please check my [codepen](https://codepen.io/mohamedsamy92/pen/aNWJoR)

Comment: Fixed position is set relative to the document as far as I know, even when you put it inside a relative div. However you may try absolute. Or maybe use some javascript to keep it always the bottom.

Comment: i tried to make it absolute , but with scroll not working :( @Gacci

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is to have the textarea always visible in the bottom of the chat.

I would suggest you to avoid doing that with position fixed since it would overlap your chat-messages.

I suggest you to change the HTML markup from:

```
<div class="converstion">
  // Conversation content
  <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```

to:

```
<div class="chatwrapper">
  <div class="conversation">
    // Conversation content
  </div>
  <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```

That way your conversation remains scrollable but your textarea will always be at the bottom without worrying about overlapping.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  font-size: 14px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
html,
body {
  position: relative;
}
.main {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.people,
.conversation {
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.people {
  background: #f1f1f1;
  width: 50px;
}
.conversation {
  width: 250px;
}
.conversation-list {
  height: calc(100% - 80px);
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.conversation-list > li {
  height: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
}
.write-message {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="people">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="conversation">
    <ul class="conversation-list">
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
      <li>5</li>
      <li>6</li>
      <li>7</li>
      <li>8</li>
    </ul>
    <textarea class="write-message" placeholder="Write your message"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```